# MySQL order blocks of 5 minutes intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, datetime, sql-order-by

this is what I have on the database:

```
data                   table    status_ord
2019-08-20 15:30:12    tab1     1
2019-08-20 15:30:30    tab2     1
2019-08-20 15:31:31    tab2     2
2019-08-20 15:31:40    tab1     1
2019-08-20 15:31:55    tab1     1
2019-08-20 15:32:12    tab2     1
2019-08-20 15:32:35    tab2     1
2019-08-20 15:50:45    tab1     1
2019-08-20 15:55:52    tab2     1
2019-08-20 12:30:12    tab1     2
2019-08-20 12:35:35    tab2     2
2019-08-20 12:45:44    tab1     2
```

I need to sort first by status_ord, i need to have first all those with status 1 and then those with status 2.
Then I need every 5 minute interval to be sorted by table and everything must be sorted by date.

to have this output:

```
data                   table    status_ord
2019-08-20 15:30:12    tab1     1
2019-08-20 15:31:40    tab1     1
2019-08-20 15:31:55    tab1     1
-- first 5 minutes block of tab 1
2019-08-20 15:30:30    tab2     1
2019-08-20 15:32:12    tab2     1
2019-08-20 15:32:35    tab2     1
-- first 5 minutes block of tab 2
2019-08-20 15:50:45    tab1     1
2019-08-20 15:55:52    tab2     1
2019-08-20 12:30:12    tab1     2
2019-08-20 12:35:35    tab2     2
2019-08-20 12:45:44    tab1     2
2019-08-20 15:31:31    tab2     2
```

I just know how to sort data for status and date like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Ordine u
ORDER BY u.status_ord ASC, u.data
```

I hope I was clear. Thank you!

Comment: Define '5 minutes'.

Comment: @Strawberry for example, in the first, from 15.30 to 15.35, i want to have first all the "tab1" and then all the "tab2"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can round datetime down to 5 minute interval using integer arithmetic:

```
SELECT *
     , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`data`) div (5 * 60) * (5 * 60) AS ts
FROM t
ORDER BY `status_ord`, `ts`, `table`
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=682519b2b4a6fc5cd486cf9009c440e8)

Comment: looks almost perfect, but on my DB the second block is not ordered by data ( not a problem for me just asking why) -- anyway there is a way to start calculating the 5 minutes from the time of the first "tab"?

Comment: @Mattek you could subtract the first timestamp from each timestamp and then integer-divide the result by 5x60 and multiply by 5x60. As for ordering I just tried to match the output, you perhaps need to re-arrange the columns in order by clause.

Comment: for "first tab", I meant the first of each block, how can I calculate the first of each tab, the query will be SELECT *
     , SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`data`) - XXXX ) div (5 * 60) * (5 * 60) AS ts
FROM t
ORDER BY `status_ord`, `ts`, `table ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
             (SELECT `data`, `table`, status_ord, 1 AS **rowOrder**
              FROM Ordine
              WHERE `table` = 'tab1'
              ORDER BY status_ord ASC , data) AS tab1 
UNION 
             SELECT `data`, `table`, status_ord, 2 AS **rowOrder**
             FROM Ordine
             WHERE `table` = 'tab2'
             ORDER BY **rowOrder** , status_ord ASC , data
```

Comment: Yea, I had already thought of this solution, the problem is that I don't know before, how many ”tab” I could have